# File Management in Mac Recovery Mode

Tags: hard-drive, mac, backup, file-recovery, macos-bigsur

I tried to update my mac to OS Big Sur, however, it's failed. I checked the storage and there was only a few MB storage. So it might happen because of the lack of storage.

After I found that I tried to reinstall the previous os (Catalina) to delete some installed applications, but it was also failed(Safeboot doesn't work too). I need to consider how I can delete some items in Mac Recovery Mode to make more space in storage. I checked disk utility in recovery mode, but it seems capable to delete only the whole disk (I can only see "used" and "others" in the disk utility). Is there any way to check and delete items one by one in Mac Recovery Mode?

I also did some research about Target Disk Mode but it might be available only for Mac to Mac communicaitons (unfortuantely, I have only windows laptops expcept the macbook with this issue):
[Accessing a Macbook Pro in Target Disk mode over Thunderbolt from Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/536395/accessing-a-macbook-pro-in-target-disk-mode-over-thunderbolt-from-windows)

If I have a backup, I can use TimeMachine but I also don't have a backup. So I'm now considering how I can manage this problem.

Comment: Precisely which Mac? Depending on model you may need to take it to Apple.

Comment: It's Macbook pro(Retina, 13inch, late 2015). And I found a terminal in Mac Recovery Mode, so this is solved. But thank you very much the comment.